# Can't Rollback Transaction in using block when exception occurred

Tags: c#, entity-framework, transactions

I am not able to rollback transaction if some exception occurred in using block of unit of work.

Here is my code:

```
using(var scope = new UnitOfWork()) 
{
        var entities = employeeRepository.Search(x => x.IsActive == true && x.IsDeleted == false);
        DateTime latestDate = LastVersionDate(Type);
        switch (type)
        {
            case EmployeeReportType.New:
                entities = entities.Where(x => x.CreatedOn >= latestDate);
                break;
            case EmployeeReportType.Modified:
                entities = entities.Where(x => x.UpdatedOn >= latestDate);
                break;
            default:
                throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
        LogToDatabase(Type, userId); // Here I am logging Report Downloading Time.


        // Here exception is occurred.
        var list = entities.Any() ? entities.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new EmployeeReportModel(x)).ToList() : new List<EmployeeReportModel>();  

        return list;
}  // transaction successfully commit (Which is wrong because  exception is occurred)
```

LogToDatabase method add entry in my log table

LastVersionDate method get last downloaded report date

Comment: what ORM are you using

Comment: Entity framework 6

Comment: It doesn't look like you are saving any data with the above code, so why does it matter if the transaction does not rollback at the database level?

Comment: LogToDatabase method add entry in my log table  and LastVersionDate method get last downloaded report date

Comment: Shouldn't you only log to the database if the download is successful?  Can't you just move the `LogToDatabase` call to just before you return the list?  If there is an exception, then that call will not be made.

Comment: Note that all statements until `LogToDatabase` don't execute any database interaction. I don't know what you're logging?